# How to fix Shutter?

Tags: shutter

Error message:

```
WARNING: Net::DBus::GLib is missing --> Ubuntu One support will be disabled!

WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> writing Exif information will be disabled!

Can't locate Pod/Usage.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/share/shutter/resources/modules /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/shutter/resources/modules/Shutter/App/Options.pm line 36.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/shutter/resources/modules/Shutter/App/Options.pm line 36.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/shutter line 151.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: hey what version of Ubuntu you are using ?

Answer (score 5):

```
WARNING: Net::DBus::GLib is missing --> Ubuntu One support will be disabled!
```

This is fixed specifically by running in a terminal `sudo apt-get install libnet-dbus-glib-perl`

```
WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> writing Exif information will be disabled!
```

This is fixed specifically by running `sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl`

The error about Line 151 means that you are missing a Shutter perl module (or it can't be found for some other reason) and not just missing a required library. Line 151 requires Options.pm, which on my 12.10 system (sorry, I don't have a 12.04 install handy right now) is at `/usr/share/perl5/Shutter/App/Options.pm`

You may want to try purging and doing a fresh install of Shutter. In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge shutter
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Answer (score 2):

Its look like some packages are missing , these are the required packages for Ubuntu 12.04  installation.

Open your terminal and type as

```
 sudo apt-get install libcommon-sense-perl libextutils-depends-perl libextutils-pkgconfig-perl
  libfile-which-perl libgnome2-canvas-perl libgnome2-gconf-perl libgnome2-perl
  libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl libgnomevfs2-extra libgoo-canvas-perl
  libgoocanvas-common libgoocanvas3 libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl
  libgtkimageview0 libhttp-server-simple-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl
  libnet-dbus-perl libpath-class-perl libproc-processtable-perl
  libproc-simple-perl libsort-naturally-perl libtie-ixhash-perl
  libwww-mechanize-perl libx11-protocol-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl
  libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl
  libxml-simple-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl perlmagick shutter
  libunicode-map8-perl libunicode-string-perl xml-twig-tools imagemagick-doc
  gnome-web-photo libnet-dropbox-api-perl libimage-exiftool-perl
  libnet-dbus-glib-perl
```

then try again.